# Is it better (from a maintenance perspective) to dynamically construct complex SQL queries using Jinja or String concatenation?

Tags: database, python, sql, query

Two possibilities. Which is better, with respect to readability, maintenance and clean code:

SQL injection can be disregarded.

1. Constructing complex parameterized sql queries using python string concatenation. Up to 7 parameters each adding an additional where condition, order by logic or wrapping a subquery into a new select. The sql string construction for a specific request is handled by a python function that calls other functions that add parts to the SQL string.
2. Using the Jinja templating language for the SQL query construction. There is a base.sql template that will be extended for specific requests with a main SQL query and Jinja macros handle additional logic. SQL lives inside .sql files.  For a specific request a python function is called that opens the corresponding .sql file, passes the parameters and Jinja builds the final SQL query.

Comment: see [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) -- _"if you... don't want your question to get instantly closed... - try to keep Gorilla vs. Shark in mind."_

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the third solution: **rewrite your code so that you won't need a templating engine to build the SQL query in the first place**.

Seriously, when queries get that much complex that you need to ask this question, you're doing it wrong, and you are building a headache for your future yourself. The symptoms include:

- Dizziness when looking at the code you've built.
- High rate of [WTF per minute](https://www.osnews.com/story/19266/wtfsm/) during code reviews.
- Bad words from your colleagues who have to maintain this thing and jump between code, template and the database itself.
- Bad words from DBAs if they ever find what you've done.
- Lower performance if your query changes all the time (and if it doesn't, why would you need a templating engine?)
- SQL Injection. You discarded it now, and maybe you're perfectly correct, but it will haunt you sooner or later. “Oh, who could have imagined that this five years old piece of code would be used *this* way?!”
- Difficulty testing.

Context: for the past week, I worked on some legacy code where there is an SQL query which spans 200+ lines and which is built dynamically. It's not a fun experience.